# Load local resources (css, js, images) to WebView Source in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin WebView to display some local html pages that are located under (FileSystem.AppDataDirectory) that is "C:/Users/nameUser/AppData/Local/Packages/....../LocalState/**folder**/file.html"

 
Under **folder** directory, beside the .html file there are other resources like .js and .css, and images. 
I'm able to load html using a StreamReader and put the html code in a variable but I can't load the resource.

```
string html = "";
HtmlWebViewSource source = new HtmlWebViewSource();

string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "index.html"); <br>
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))<br>
{ <br>
     html = sr.ReadToEnd(); <br>
}<br>
source.Html = @html; <br>
source.BaseUrl = folderPath; //path that contains css and js resources <br> 
webView.Source = source;
```

So I'm able to view the Html code but I can't load the resources.
Is there a way to solve this issues?

Comment: You need to provide the resource path through dependency services for each platform. Each platform have their own path for the resources. Also, on the top of my head I'm not sure if the default webview supports this, but we used FormsWebView for this purpose in your project.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content

Comment: I'm working with Xamarin.UWP. The resources are downloaded with CrossDowloadManager and are located through a local path in disk, not in Application Assets

Comment: @Shaw could you please show me how you implemented it in your code? Thanks a lot